# Return Data from Axios

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to return the response from an axios API call. I don't quite get what a promise is and all the tutorials/information I find they only log the response, I want to return it.

Here is what I have, but when I call getPokemon it's undefined.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getPokemon = () => {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Response:", response.data.results);
        return response.data.results;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return null;
    });
}

export {getPokemon};
```

Comment: If you don't understand promises, using axios will be very challenging. Start with e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises. But getPokemon doesn't return *anything*, promise or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a React app then you want to do your Axios call in `componentDidMount`. Axios automatically returns a promise.

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          data: res.data.results
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    let pokemon = this.state.data;
    let display = Object.values(pokemon).map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <p>{item.url}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
    <div>{display}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Doing it like this will send the Axios request after the React app has loaded and set the JSON data in the component state. You should be able to access the JSON data via `this.state.data`.

Check out this [Codepen example with working API call](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-snow-xc187).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, I suggest you read about promises.
a good method for achieving what you need is by using async/await syntax check out the following code:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const getPokemon = async () => {
    try{
       let res = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');
       return res.data.results;
    }
    catch(error){
      return null //that's what you did in your code.
    }
}

export {getPokemon};
```

Comment: Using syntax of either kind isn't a good method of achieving reading about something. *"that's what you did in your code"* - no, they returned `undefined` in success and fail cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove ".result"

```
const axios = require("axios");
    
const getPokemon = async () => {
   try {
      let res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      return res.data; **here remove his .result**
   } catch (error) {
      return null; //that's what you did in your code.
   }
};
    
export default getPokemon;
```

2. In index.js or any page call it:

```
import getPokemon from "./GetPokimon";
const xyz = async () => {
   const data = await getPokemon();
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));//u will see the data here
}
xyz(); //calling getPokemon()
```